# Selenium: NoSuchFrameException for Chrome Extension

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Chrome extension and I'd like to test it with Selenium. The extension places an iframe tag to pages.

I can successfully get the iframe tag by running the following command:

```
top_frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//iframe[@class="top-frame"]')
```

However, when I try switching to the frame I get 'NoSuchFrameException' error.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(top_frame)
```

The following line outputs the frame's class name correctly

```
print(top_frame.get_attribute('class'))
```

Error log:

```
Testing http://www.google.com

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/run_tests.py", line 200, in <module>
    main()
  File "test/run_tests.py", line 197, in main
    run_tests(args.plugin, args.out, args.url)
  File "test/run_tests.py", line 167, in run_tests
    button = check_button(driver, url)
  File "test/run_tests.py", line 84, in check_button
    driver.switch_to.frame(top_frame)
  File "/home/burak/.virtualenv/extension/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/switch_to.py", line 87, in frame
    self._driver.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_FRAME, {'id': frame_reference})
  File "/home/burak/.virtualenv/extension/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/burak/.virtualenv/extension/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame: element is not a frame
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.90)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Linux 4.10.0-30-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: The frame may not be getting initialized. Because browser may be blocking the frame itself?

Comment: Yet, I can get the frame. I suppose that the initialization of the frame is not the issue.

Comment: are you currently on some other frame than mentioned frame?

Comment: No, I'm on the frame that I mentioned. Cause top_frame.get_attribute('class') method call gives me the class name of the frame that I want.

Comment: try this code and let me know if it works for you- top_frame = `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//iframe[@class="top-frame"]')
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(top_frame)`

Comment: Tried. It's the same.

Comment: The error `NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame: element is not a frame` says it all. The element to which you are trying to switch is not a frame element. Can you share your code block and the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of Chrome, most likely there is a bug that breaks the switch_to_frame() call. Therefore, I started using Firefox instead, everything is smooth for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this man,

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,value=".//iframe[@src='give your frame source name here..']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This link is to the associated issue report on Chromium. It has not been resolved yet. (25/10/17)
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2019